# Is it possible to connect Debezium with Postgresql which is not in docker?

Tags: postgresql, docker, cdc, debezium, postgresql-12

Currently I am using PostgreSQL 12 in my WSL2 environment, I wish to implement cdc with debezium and kafka. As I am a first timer to do this, My searched all tutorial showing this process with docker.

In my case no issue with docker if it is not about postgres. I dont want to use postgres/docker.

I just simply want to connect debezium and kafka to my existing postgres on disk. please suggest me tutorial or way how i can connect. It will be a huge help. Thanks.

I did these two steps:

> step 1

`docker run -it --rm --name zookeeper_debezium -p 2181:2181 -p 2888:2888 -p 3888:3888 debezium/zookeeper:1.2`

> step 2

`docker run -it --rm --name kafka -p 9092:9092 --link zookeeper_debezium:zookeeper debezium/kafka:1.2`

Comment: `debezium and kafka` are running docker?

Comment: Yes @Adiii  Only postgres in disk

Comment: Can your share your existing steps you did for debezium or docker image?

Comment: setp 1: docker run -it --rm --name zookeeper_debezium -p 2181:2181 -p 2888:2888 -p 3888:3888 debezium/zookeeper:1.2 step 2: docker run -it --rm --name kafka -p 9092:9092 --link zookeeper_debezium:zookeeper debezium/kafka:1.2 .... Now what to do

Comment: better to add them i the question [Edit question]https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62688314/edit

Answer (score 0):

please follow this tutorial - https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/tutorial.html

There are few differences in your situation

- You will not start any database in container, neither MySQL nor PostgreSQL
- Your registration request (https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/tutorial.html#registering-connector-monitor-inventory-database) will be modified for PostgreSQL connector
- You must setup your database following https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.2/connectors/postgresql.html#postgresql-server-configuration
- As you use PostgreSQL 12 I recommend you to use `pgoutput` (https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.2/connectors/postgresql.html#postgresql-pgoutput) plugin. Thus you can skip the step about libraries